# function declaration while trying to print binary tree contents

Tags: c

I have been trying to write a function to print the contents of a binary tree where the left most branch is nearest to A and furthest right in nearest to Z.
However due to how I have written the program I have two functions that call each other which results in one being implicitly defined, is there an easier way to do this~? / can i fix it?

```
/* print() */
static void print (char title[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH+1] , char author[MAX_AUTHOR_LENGTH+1] , int year , int printed , int np , struct Book *print_pointer)
{
fprintf (stderr , "print called");
if (print_pointer->printed == 0)
{
printf ("\nTitle: %s\n" , print_pointer->title);
printf ("Author: %s\n" , print_pointer->author);
printf ("Year: %i\n" , print_pointer->year);
print_pointer->printed = 1;
np++;
print_pointer = book_tree;
}
}

/* descend_right() */
void descend_right (char title[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH+1] , char author[MAX_AUTHOR_LENGTH+1] , int year , int printed , int np , struct Book *print_pointer)
{
fprintf (stderr , "descend_right called");
if (print_pointer->right->printed == 0) 
{
print_pointer = print_pointer->right;
descend_left(title , author , year , printed , np , print_pointer);
}
if (print_pointer->right == NULL) 
{
print(title , author , year , printed , np , print_pointer);
}
if (print_pointer->right->printed == 1) 
{
descend_right(title , author , year , printed , np , print_pointer);
}
}

/* descend_left() */
void descend_left (char title[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH+1] , char author[MAX_AUTHOR_LENGTH+1] , int year , int printed , int np , struct Book *print_pointer)
{
fprintf (stderr , "descend_left called");
if (print_pointer->left->printed == 0) 
{
print_pointer = print_pointer->left; 
descend_left(title , author , year , printed , np , print_pointer);
}
if (print_pointer->left == NULL) 
{
print(title , author , year , printed , np , print_pointer);
descend_right(title , author , year , printed , np , print_pointer);
}
if (print_pointer->left->printed == 1) 
{
print(title , author , year , printed , np , print_pointer);
descend_right(title , author , year , printed , np , print_pointer);
}
}

/* menu_print_database(): */
static void menu_print_database (char title[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH+1] , char author[MAX_AUTHOR_LENGTH+1] , int year , int printed , int bn)
{
struct Book *print_pointer = book_tree;
int np = 0;
do 
{
if (book_tree->left->printed == 1 && book_tree->right->printed == 0) print(title , author , year , printed , np , print_pointer);
if (print_pointer->printed == 0) descend_left (title , author , year , printed , np , print_pointer);
if (print_pointer->printed == 1) descend_right (title , author , year , printed , np , print_pointer);
}
while (np != bn);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a forward declaration of one of the functions, like this:

```
static void print (char title[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH+1] , char author[MAX_AUTHOR_LENGTH+1] , int year , int printed , int np , struct Book *print_pointer);
void descend_right (char title[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH+1] , char author[MAX_AUTHOR_LENGTH+1] , int year , int printed , int np , struct Book *print_pointer);
void descend_left (char title[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH+1] , char author[MAX_AUTHOR_LENGTH+1] , int year , int printed , int np , struct Book *print_pointer);
```

This serves as a promise to the compiler to define these functions some time later in the code of your program. It tells the compiler the names of the functions, their return types, and the types of their parameters - everything that it needs to know to produce an invocation of the function.

Add these three lines before the first function to fix the problem.